# preg replace with regex between

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to remove a piece of string that begins between `Int.` and newline.

```
$string = preg_replace('/Int.[\s\S]+?\n/', '', $string);
```

Here is the source string:

```
My address
Int. blabla
blabla blabla
```

Is that possible?

Comment: please always include the expected result into the question body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
$s = "My address\nInt. blabla\nblabla blabla";
$s = preg_replace('~Int\.\h*([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]*~', '', $s);
echo $s; // => My address\nblabla blabla
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/57uhYO)

The regex will match `Int.`, then zero or more spaces (`\h*`, just to left-trim the result) and then will capture into Group 1 one or more characters other than line feed and carriage return symbols (`([^\r\n]+)`)

Comment: Do you ever sleep, Wiktor?

Comment: @Jan usleep maybe :) :) :)

Comment: I slept some 6 hours - enough :) I will sleep it off on Saturday and Sunday.

Comment: Stdout: blablabla? Shouldn't be there "My address" as well?

Comment: @AMartinNo1: *begins between "Int." and newline.* The negated character class `[^\r\n]` with `+` quantifier matches 1+ characters other than newline symbols.

Comment: @HalayemAnis: Made my day :-) Just found [`time-nanosleep(0,1)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time-nanosleep.php) - maybe that's what he's into...

Comment: If I get him correct he wants it to be removed not extracted but it's possible I am the one who is sleeping. Didn't had my coffee yet.

Comment: @AMartinNo1: I need a coffee, too :)

Comment: As I said, I needed coffee. @Erik, please always include the expected result into the question body :)

Answer (score 1):

To remove your string, just use the following code:

```
$string = "My address\nInt. blabla\nblabla blabla";
$regex = '~       # delimiter
          ^Int\.  # Looks for Int. at the beginning of a line
          .*      # everything else except a newline
          ~xm';   # free spacing mode and multiline
$replacement = '';
$string = preg_replace($regex, $replacement, $string);
```

You need the modifiers `x` to allow the comments and `m` to allow the caret (`^`) to match at any line.
If you want to remove the whole line (including a newline character, that is), change the regex to:

```
$regex = '~^Int\..*\R~m';
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/fYJEJA).